# Jquery passing 2 id in .not( ) function

Tags: jquery

```
$("#bbody").children().not("#" + pageid && "#show")
```

Such kind of thing is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the comma selector:

```
.not("#show, #" + pageid);
```

or use two passes:

```
.not("#show").not("#" + pageid);
```

Answer (score 0):

just put a comma between two id, it will apply for two elements

```
$("#bbody").children().not("#" + pageid + ",#show")
```

Answer (score 0):

for multi [not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) condition you need to put inside the selectors you want to avoid. 
for [multi](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) select add a comma for each condition.

```
$("#bbody").children().not("#" + pageid + ",#show");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try it .... it's work

```
$("#bbody").not('#' + pageid).not('#show')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use comma:

```
$("#body").children().not("#" + pageid + ", #show")
```